# DotTrace, Is it possible to modify code on MVC5 Web App during profile session and rerun....?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, dottrace

I am using DotTrace 2018.3 to profile a MVC5 Web App on IIS Express, within Visual Studio 2017.

Often I start profiling using "Sampling", spot the bottleneck, and then want to make a code correction, and then see the effect. At the moment it seems I have to kill the first profile session, make the correction and then startup a new profile session which is ok, but...

In summary is there a more efficient way to profile when refactoring out performance issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to rebuild and restart your app (and restart a profiling session) each time you make a code correction. Unfortunately, there is no more efficient way.